# Finding Two-Sample T-Test's p value by using scipy.t.sf

Tags: python, scipy, p-value

I'm trying to use `scipy.t.sf` to calculate the p-value for a two-sample T-test. I know that the easiest way to do this is to use `scipy.stats.ttest_ind`, but I was hoping to deepen my understanding and look at the math and come up with alternative methods.

My original code is:

```
import scipy.stats as st
test1 = (8,7,10,5,7)
test2 = (9,5,12,8)
result = st.ttest_ind(test1, #men's sample data
                       test2, #women's sample data
                       alternative = 'less', #alternative hypothesis is that women's waiting time is longer than men's
                       equal_var=False) #perform Welch’s t-test, which does not assume equal population variance.
pvalue = result.pvalue
```

The output is Ttest_indResult(statistic=-0.6641304531560304, pvalue=0.2684710269367842)

However, when I tried to solve for the pvalue using `scipy.t.sf`, I cannot get the 0.26847 statistic.

```
test_1 = np.array(test1)
test_2 = np.array(test2) 
test_mean = test_1.mean()
ctrl_mean = test_2.mean()
mean_diff = test_mean - ctrl_mean
test_var = test_1.var()/(test_1.shape[0]-1)
ctrl_var = test_2.var()/(test_2.shape[0]-1)

tt = mean_diff/math.sqrt(test_var + ctrl_var) # (test_mean - ctrl_mean) / sqrt(var(test_mean - ctrl_mean))
n = min(test_1.shape[0],test_2.shape[0])
pval = st.t.sf(np.abs(tt), n-1)
```

The output is now (t = -0.6641304531560304, pvalue = 0.2770449975228821). As you can see, t is consistent with our observation from the `scipy.stats.ttest_ind` method; however, the pvalue is not. Any changes I could make to the code to get the 0.26847 number? Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

The difference comes from the fact that your degrees of freedom are not the same across methods. In the first method, you use Welch t-test which means you have a degree of freedom of around 4.8377. You can see this using `result.df` (need Scipy version >=1.11) or use the formula in the code below. In the second method you use `df = n-1` which equals 3. This is why you get different p-values.

If you want to reproduce the same test manually, you need first to compute the right degree of freedom. Note that `scipy.stats.ttest_ind` uses the corrected variance with delta degree of freedom = 1 for computing `df` (see the [Wikipedia entry on Welch t-test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Welch%27s_t-test) which is the reference in `ttest_ind`, it is stated there that the [corrected sample standard deviation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation#Corrected_sample_standard_deviation) is used, hence we need to use the corrected variance `var(ddof=1)` when computing `df`).

```
# Compute s^2/N (this makes the df equation a bit clearer)
test_1_nvar = test_1.var(ddof = 1)/test_1.shape[0]  
test_2_nvar = test_2.var(ddof = 1)/test_2.shape[0]
df = (test_1_nvar + test_2_nvar)**2 / (test_1_nvar**2/(test_1.shape[0]-1) + test_2_nvar**2/(test_2.shape[0]-1))
```